# Boot problems after installing package `android`. How do I fix it?

Tags: boot, 14.04, android, lxc

I was thinking to play with my android phone through usb, so I did an `apt-get install android*` on my laptop. This this broke my boot. I can not boot it normally, but if I go into recovery and then resume, it boots OK (though graphics are running slower).

I then removed the android packages with `apt-get remove android*`, but this didn't fix it. The boot hangs as pictured below.

[image: boot screen]

The logs for the boot are nowhere to found. But I found this in /var/log/dmesg

```
[   21.073633] init: Failed to spawn lxc-android-config main process: unable to execute: No such file or directory
[   21.081249] init: adbd-emergency-shell pre-start process (894) terminated with status 2
[   21.785001] init: udev-fallback-graphics main process (917) terminated with status 1
[   23.425461] init: ureadahead-touch main process (664) terminated with status 1
[   23.456583] init: lxc-android-boot main process (1012) terminated with status 127
[   23.546875] init: friendly-recovery post-stop process (658) terminated with status 1
[   23.547479] init: failsafe main process (1010) killed by TERM signal
[   24.375532] init: set.pretty-hostname main process (1157) terminated with status 127
```

What did I do and how to fix this. Any suggestions?

Comment: @terdon Edited and added a more readable shot.

Comment: Thanks, that's much better. No idea why installing those packages would have broken your boot though. The messages are not informative at all. Perhaps you can find something of interest in `/var/log/boot`.

Comment: `Package: android  Description: android Ubuntu Touch images  This is the android portion of Ubuntu Touch images.` ***THINK*** before you install packages! Only install the ones you need, because some will break your installation by just doing something you don't expect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I experienced this recently whilst playing around with Ubuntu Touch and Android linux containers (lxc). the symptom was my system would hang on the boot-up splash screen (after entering my LUKS passphrase).

I fixed this by going into recovery mode and deleting /etc/ureadahead-touch.conf and doing a complete removal in Synaptic of android-tools-adb, android-tools-fastboot lxc-android-config and ubuntu-device-flash.

From the command line the following should work:

```
sudo rm  /etc/ureadahead-touch.conf
sudo apt-get purge android-tools-adb android-tools-fastboot lxc-android-config ubuntu-device-flash
```

I'm not sure which of these was causing the problem, but they were all putting stuff in /etc which may have been causing the problem. After this my system booted up normally. Most likely it was the lxc-android-config stuff causing problems.

Hopefully this will save other people from the same issue in the future. It was also helpful to disable the Ubuntu splash screen, by disabling plymouth.

Comment: I deleted `/etc/init/ureadahead-touch.conf` and purged `lxc-android-config`, which solved my issue. I didn't have `ubuntu-device-flash` but can confirm it is unrelated to `android-tools-*`.

Comment: Matthew saved my day.

Answer (score -3):

You have to uninstall android-tools-**adbd**

And then reboot